# 2017 was prime. 2018=2 x 1009 is double a prime. What does the future portend?

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-gaps

What is the likelihood in the future that a year will be prime or double a prime? Are these years rare? Dependent on the prime gaps? What's the best proven frequency?

Happy New Year! :-)

Comment: ...and $\,2019 = 3 \cdot 673\,$ is thrice a prime ;-) Happy New Year!

Comment: As a partial answer, the probability, in a sense, that a given year $n$ is prime is given by $1/\ln(n)$. This is, sort of, the prime number theorem.

Comment: For the next 50 years, the only primes are: 2027, 2029, 2039, 2053, 2063; and the only double primes are: 2018, 2026, 2038, 2042, 2062, 2066. Happy New Year!

Comment: Perhaps I should say, "2017 *is* prime." But you know what I mean... :-)

Comment: @dxiv And we only have to wait less than 2 centuries for the first occurrence in the $21$st century of a year that's a perfect square of a prime ($47^2 = 2209$). :)

Comment: I'm also pretty sure that the probability $n/2$ is prime, given that $n$ is prime, is again $1/ln(n)$, since there's an obvious symmetry between half the even integers and just the integers. Given this, we can easily calculate the probability that $n$ is twice a prime as being $\frac{1}{2\ln(n)}$, using the definition of conditional probability. I'm not posting this as an answer because I'm not confident that the probability of $n/2$ being prime given that $n$ is even is actually (actually approximately) $1/\ln(n)$, but I would believe it.

Comment: ^The start of this should read "...$n/2$ is prime, given that $n$ is **even**..."

Comment: Credit [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2589834/291201) for the "*trio primes*" [reference](http://oeis.org/A036570). Roughly five centuries for the next trio (2557), hundreds more for the next [quartet](http://oeis.org/A278585) (12721).