# How many "quartets" are there?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, prime-numbers

> $2017 /1=  2017$, a prime;
>   $2018/2 =  1009$, a prime; and
>   $2019/3 =  673$, a prime.

Call such a sequence a **trio**.
If $2020/4 = 505$ were prime, then we would have a **quartet** and similarly for a **quintet**, etc. But $505$ is not prime so this is not a quartet. I haven't found any quartets (yet) although trios are not hard to find.

**Question:** How many quartets are there?

Let's identify a sequence by its initial prime.
Observe that a prime can be a trio prime only if it is $13$ or it is $=1$ or $37$ mod $60$.
And it can be a quartet prime only if it is $=1$ mod $120$.
My calculations, with assistance from Alexa, indicate that the trio primes less than $2017$ are:
$13, 37,  157, 421, 541, 877, 1201, 1381, \text { and } 1621.$

EDIT: $421$ is **not** a trio prime. I can't blame this on Alexa.

Comment: Related: [2017 was prime. 2018=2 x 1009 is double a prime. What does the future portend?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2587182/2017-was-prime-2018-2-x-1009-is-double-a-prime-what-does-the-future-portend).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The trio primes are [A036570](http://oeis.org/A036570) on OEIS (it's always a good idea to look up a sequence on the OEIS if you've managed to compute its first few terms) and that entry has a link to the the quartet primes, which are [A278585](http://oeis.org/A278585) plus one; the smallest one is apparently $12721$, where

- $12721$ is prime,
- $12722 = 2 \cdot 6361$ and $6361$ is prime,
- $12723 = 3 \cdot 4241$ and $4241$ is prime, and
- $12724 = 4 \cdot 3181$ and $3181$ is prime.

Probably there are infinitely many of these although this is quite beyond current technology; it would follow from a suitable generalization of the [prime k-tuple conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_k-tuple), and would imply that there are infinitely many primes $p$ such that $2p-1$ is prime, which is just as open as the infinitude of the [Sophie Germain primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime).

Comment: I did use OEIS (as well as contribute to them) but they said the sequence didn't exist! I was pretty excited. It turns out I had made an error in the fourth term. So now we have a new tool to check our work.

Comment: 19441 is a **quintet prime** using OEIS A278585 and Alexa.